# Find folders that begin with the same string

Tags: bash, files, scripting, sort

I have more than 1000 subdirectories in a folder. Some of them begin with the same string and I want to find all directories where the first 5 characters of their name are also the first 5 of another directory.

I don't want to search for a specific string, I need a way of reading the name of the first subdirectory and comparing it to the first 5 characters of the the names of the other subdirectories. I then need to repeat the process for the second subdir etc.

All such names found should be written to a text file.

Comment: How many characters are the "first 'x' characters"?

Comment: 5 is sufficient I guess.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What do you mean "you guess"? It's your question, don't you know? And what do you mean by 5? Exactly 5? At least 5? Five or more?

Comment: So, you want the count of matching names for each (fixed-width) prefix? Perhaps something like `ls | cut -c '1-5'  | sort | uniq -c`.

Comment: Do the 1000+ sudirectories in this folder themselves have similarly affected subfolders?  And just to be sure, the search is for *folder* names only, not regular files?  Also is there only *one* duplicated 5 char string, or are there *several* distinct duplicate strings?

Comment: When asking a question, always explain what you have tried. This way we can help you find where you went wrong, and next time you'll be able to figure it out own your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below command will do what you're after.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | uniq -D -w 7
```

The `find` lists all the directories in the current directory, filters them through `sort` (a prerequisite to using `uniq`), and then uses `uniq` to print all duplicates, using only the first 7 characters for comparison. We use 7 characters instead of 5, because the first 2 characters are going to be `./`.

Comment: Oh man, why didn't I think of that? You might want to also include `find .  -type d -print0  | sort -z | uniq -zD -w 7 | tr '\0' '\n'` to deal with possible newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion to check the first 5 characters of a string.

Just loop over the sorted dirnames. The directories with the same prefix should be adjacent in such a list.

`$keep` contains the first directory with a different prefix, `$printed` is a flag that prevents the `$keep` being printed several times if there are several directories with the same prefix.

```
#! /bin/bash
printed=0
keep=''
for dir in */ ; do
    if [[ ${dir:0:5} == ${keep:0:5} ]] ; then
        if ((!printed)) ; then
            echo "$keep"
            printed=1
        fi
        echo "$dir"
    else
        printed=0
        keep=$dir
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If your directory names don't contain spaces, you can do:

```
find . -type d -printf '%f\n' | 
    perl -lne '/.{1,5}/; push @{$k{$&}},$_; 
               END{ 
                    map{print if scalar(@{$k{$_}})>1}keys(%k)
               }' > results.txt
```

That will find all subdirectories of the current directory and print their names (`-printf '%f\n'`, this assumes your `find` supports `printf`). The `perl` script takes the 1st 5 characters of each name and uses them as keys for a hash of arrays whose values are the directory names. Then, any names names that were found more than once are printed.

If your directory names can contain newlines, you can ad `BEGIN{$/="\0"}` at the beginning of the Perl script:

```
find . -type d -printf '%f\0' | 
    perl -lne 'BEGIN{$/="\0"} /.{1,5}/; push @{$k{$&}},$_; 
               END{
                 map{print if scalar(@{$k{$_}})>1}keys(%k)
               }' > results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions and and the posted solutions! I ended up using `find . - maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | uniq -zD -w 7 | tr '\0' '\n'`

Although it not shows the output in proper alphabetical order BUT the "duplicates" are shown adjacent - and that's the more important thing.
Learned a lot here (again :-)